# Get associated entities to an entity in doctrine but with rule

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

I want to retrieve all the followers associated to a user, but with a certain rule. Only the ones that have the type 0. Here is the user entity methods that retrieves the followers from the follow table:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Follow", mappedBy="following")
     */
    protected $followers;


---------------


/**
     * Add Followers
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Follow $follow
     * @return DealFlowCore
     */
    public function addFollower(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Follow $followers)
    {
    $this->followers[] = $followers;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove Followers
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Follow $followers
 */
public function removeFollower(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Follow $followers)
{
    $this->followers->removeElement($followers);
}

/**
 * Get Followers
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getFollowers()
{
    return $this->followers;
}
```

and here is the follow entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FFollow
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="f_follow")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Follow
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_follow", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer // 0 user 1 project
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type_follow", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $typeFollow;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
 * @var \FUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_following", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $following;

/**
 * @var \FUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_follower", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $follower;

public function __construct($typeFollow = 0)
{
    $this->typeFollow = $typeFollow;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set typeFollow
 *
 * @param integer $typeFollow
 * @return Follow
 */
public function setTypeFollow($typeFollow)
{
    $this->typeFollow = $typeFollow;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get typeFollow
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTypeFollow()
{
    return $this->typeFollow;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return Follow
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Set following
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $following
 * @return Follow
 */
public function setFollowing(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $following = null)
{
    $this->following = $following;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get following
 *
 * @return \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getFollowing()
{
    return $this->following;
}

/**
 * Set follower
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $follower
 * @return Follow
 */
public function setFollower(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $follower = null)
{
    $this->follower = $follower;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get follower
 *
 * @return \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getFollower()
{
    return $this->follower;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use a [custom repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) for your Followers entity.

Something like:

**/Acme/UserBundle/Repository/FollowRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Repository;


class FollowRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     public function getFollowersByUserAndType($user, $type)
     {
         $em = $this->getEntityManager();
         $query = $em->createQuery("
             SELECT f
             FROM AcmeUserBundle:Follow f
             WHERE f.following = :user 
             AND f.typeFollow = :type"
         );

         $query->setParameter('user', $user);
         $query->setParameter('type', $type);

         return $query->getResult();
     }
}
```

And then you can call it from your controller like:

```
$user = //get your user somehow
$type = 0
$followRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getManager()
                         ->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Follow');
$followers = $followRepository->getFollowersByUserAndType($user, $type);
```

Comment: Actually already thought about this... but i have a lot of templates that uses the method of the entity. ( user.getFollowers|count ). So i need to modify the method of the entity to suit this new behaviour.